# I want to use a box-and-whisker diagram plotly to oppose the vertical and horizontal axes

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I want to show the vertical and horizontal axes opposite in a box-and-whisker diagram, but I can't get it to work.
I thought I could use `fig.update_traces(orientation='h')` to reverse the vertical and horizontal axes, but I cannot successfully display a box-and-whisker diagram.
This is the image of the graph I want.This is brought from the official plotly [web](https://plotly.com/python/violin/)
[image: This is the image of the graph I want.]
*What should I do ?*

Here's what I have tried:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

data = {'one': [0.517970, 0.335520, 0.179993, 0.049795, -0.056827],
        'two': [0.457973, 0.283992, 0.136433, 0.013717, -0.085876]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Violin(y=df['one'],
                        name='one',
                        box_visible=True,
                        meanline_visible=True,
                        side='positive',
                        spanmode='soft',
                        line_color='#1f77b4',
                        opacity=0.6))

fig.add_trace(go.Violin(y=df['two'],
                        name='two',
                        box_visible=True,
                        meanline_visible=True,
                        side='positive',
                        spanmode='soft',
                        line_color='#ff7f0e',
                        opacity=0.6))

fig.update_traces(orientation='h')

fig.show()
```

Comment: Do you have a figure example of what you want?

Comment: If I change the axis designation to x, will it not be horizontal? `fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['one'],...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use x instead of y for your data:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['one'],...

fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x=df['two'],...
```